# Get class from Admin class Django

Tags: django, django-admin

```
@admin.register(Test)
class TestAdmin(AbstractTestAdmin):
```

In TestAdmin, when I use `self` I get `TestAdmin`. How can I get `Test` instead of `TestAdmin`?

When I use parent_model i get a error response:

```
'TestAdmin' object has no attribute 'parent_model'
```

It is a AbstractClass, that is why I cant just use Test. I need to get in in a different way

Comment: You've already imported `Test` when you pass it through `@admin.register(...)`, can just use `Test` in the `TestAdmin` class

Comment: @JuijV what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: It is a AbstractClass, that is why I cant just use ```Test```.  I need to get in in a different way

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
admin.ModelAdmin.get_object(self, request, object_id)
```

and it works.